# Execute a local function only once in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, local, execute

This seems so easy, but I couldn't find a proper solution yet.

What the JS does: check an element's CSS style immediately and if max-width is 1000px, do something (see JS comment).
And in case the JS is executed before the CSS is applied, check again after the document has finished loading.
But "do something" should only happen once, so if it was done right away, don't do it again via the event listener.

But how to avoid that? It would be easy using a global variable or function, but I want to keep those local.

```
(function()
{
    function checkCSS()
    {
        if (window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('max-width') == '1000px')
        {
            // do something, but only once!
        }
    }
    checkCSS();
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {checkCSS();});
})();
```

Comment: May I know what you want to achieve `// do something, but only once!`

Comment: Maybe you do not need that function at all

Comment: This line `window.getComputedStyle(element)` does not looks good. Beside `window.addEventListener('load', ` does not need to be inside an IIFE

Comment: @brk - I don't think you meant IIFE there (it's not immediately-invoked). You're absolutely spot-on that the function wrapper is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the handler when you've done the "something," see comments:

```
(function() {
    function checkCSS() {
        if (window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("max-width") === "1000px") {
            // do something, but only once!
            // *** Remove the listener
            window.removeEventListener("load", checkCSS);
        }
    }

    // *** Add the listener
    window.addEventListener("load", checkCSS); // <== Note using the function directly
    // *** Do the initial check
    checkCSS();
})();
```

Or only add it if you didn't do "something":

```
(function() {
    function checkCSS() {
        if (window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("max-width") === "1000px") {
            // do something, but only once!
            // *** We did it (you could remove the listener here, but it doesn't really matter)
            return true;
        } else {
            // *** Didn't do it
            return false;
        }
    }

    // *** Do the initial check
    if (!checkCSS()) {
        // *** Didn't do it, add the listener
        window.addEventListener("load", checkCSS); // <== Note using the function directly
    }
})();
```

Comment: Amazing, especially your second suggestion (only add it if you didn't do "something") was perfect for my purpose, works great now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To trigger it before "CSS is applied" you can use different event, for example, `DOMContentLoaded`

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkCSS)
```